# jSignature loading data as a picture

Tags: php, ajax, jsignature

Alright so I have a little problem, I am basically trying to output this data as an image but it doesnt seem to work at all.

This is the part where I save the code

```
$("#saveSig").click(function() {
            var sig = $("#signature").jSignature("getData", "base30");
            alert(sig);

            $.ajax({
                url: "handler.php",
                data: {func:"picture_insert",pic:sig},
                type: "POST",
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
```

Now I save the data as a string (I convert it from an array to a string)

```
mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO signature (signature) VALUES ('".implode("",$_POST['pic'])."')");
```

Now when I load the image

```
if($result->num_rows >= 1) {
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo "<img src='".$row['signature']."'/>";
                }
            }
```

Now here are some question I have regarding this

1. I know that the problem that I am providing the picture code instead of the image URL, how do I resolve this? Well when I am loading the picture it just shows that icon like the image doesnt exist
2. Is there any way I can just export the data as a picture instead of saving it inside the Database? If not, can I somehow load the data from the DB and then export it? If so how?
3. Since I am saving the picture as varchar inside the Database, how big should it be? Currently Ive set it to 1024 but should I increase the size? Since this thing can be quite heavy.

Comment: Are you able to get data in `$row['signature']`?

Comment: Yes. It prints the correct data. I just want to export it all as a .png or something.

Comment: Sorry no idea regarding export